# Conferming Order in Opencart 1.6

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, authorize.net

I'm using Opencart 1.6 in my store, I need a way to confirm orders before payment, I mean, I don't want to discount the payment from the customer when he/she buy anything from my store until I confirm it, is there any admin tool that can help me in confirming orders and discount the payment money from the customer, please note I'm using Authorized.net as merchant account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Opencart 1.6? http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=download/download. I can't find 1.6 in this page.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's 1.5.6.4